# $_SERVER['PHP_self'] request in form is hackable without htmlspecialchars

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, security

If I am making a form in `test.php` and `form action ="<?php echo $_SERVER[PHP_self]"?>` then it can be hacked. I understand it can be secured by `htmlspecialchars()`. But if i use `<form action ="test.php">` instead. it doesn't get hacked . What is difference here?

If I edit url test.php/blah blah then it becomes form action in source code, but it doesn't happened when `form action="test.php"`. Isn't it same thing? `test.php` and `$_server['PHP_self']`?

Comment: Define "it can be hacked".

Comment: You might also consider just leaving off the `action` attribute and letting the form submit to the current URL.

Answer (score 3):

When you assign `<form action ="test.php">` to your HTML, this code is static and cannot be manipulated server-side. If you assign the global `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, then this entry within your page is dynamic dependent on the users URL found in the address bar making it possible for them to manipulate this code like so:

***If the world was a safe and trustworthy place to live in...***

**Browser URL:** http://www.test.com/html/form.php

```
<form action="/html/index.php" method="post">
```

**Now for the real world....**

**Browser URL:** `http://test.com/form.php/%22%3E%3Cscript%3Ealert('xss')%3C
/script%3E%3Chack%22`

```
<form action="/html/index.php/"><script>alert('xss')</script><hack"" method="post">
```

This can be avoided by surrounding your `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` inside `htmlspecialchars()` function which effectively sanitizes the script so it looks like the following:

```
<form action="/html/index.php/&quot;&gt;&lt;script&gt;alert('xss')&lt;/script&gt;&lt;hack&quot;" method="post">
```